# Meaning of notation $v \mapsto ( x \mapsto f(x,v) )$

Tags: notation

I came across this notation in *[this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degenerate_form)* wiki article.

Can anyone tell me the meaning of this notation?
What exactly is happening here?

$v \mapsto ( x \mapsto f(x,v) )$

What I understand here is $x, v \in V$ and $V^*$ is its dual.

Am I correct, if I say, first vector v is fixed and

then $\forall x, x \mapsto f(x,v)$?

So that $f( . , v) \in V^*$, where dot will be filled by $x$ ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The notation $v \mapsto ( x \mapsto f(x,v) )$ means that a vector $v \in V$ is sent to the element $f(\cdot , v) \in V^*$.

Comment: So does it mean x is fixed, and v is mapped to f(x,v) ?

Comment: @Prashanth No, $x$ is not fixed. $v$ is mapped to the function that takes any $x \in V$ to $f(x, v)$.

Comment: Now it occurred to me, thanks a lot Arthur

Answer (score 7):

In general the `\mapsto` arrow $\mapsto$ is a way of defining a function without naming it. It's similar to the `lambda` construction in Scheme and Python, and I believe Maple uses `->`. So for example, you might define
$$f(x) = x^2$$
or you could write the same definition as
$$f = x \mapsto x^2$$
So the notation
$$F = v \mapsto (x \mapsto f(x,v))$$
from that Wikipedia page could also be written as
$$F(v) = x \mapsto f(x,v)$$
or using the $\cdot$ notation,
$$F(v) = f(\cdot, v)$$
Since $f$ in the Wikipedia article is supposed to be a bilinear form, if you fix one of its parameters (fill in $v$) you get a linear function from vectors to scalars.

See [Regarding the notation $f: a \mapsto b$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/651205/regarding-the-notation-f-a-mapsto-b?rq=1)

Comment: Thanks a lot Garrett, for the detailed answer